# how to access a EL variable and pass it as an argument to a function in EL?

Tags: jsf, jsp-tags, el

I want to call a function on a bean with an argument passsed to it in jsp using EL.
The problem is it does not allow something like:
"`${teacherBean.certificationFor(${particularField})`"

the thing is i want to iterate over an array and call the function certificationFor for all the values in the array passed as an argument.
I am getting the values in array by:

So Basically i want to do something like:

${teacherBean.certificationFor(${particularField})

but i cant do that.
can i do this in any other way?

I am a newbie in EL . :)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Where exactly do you want to do that and for what? Just to get a value for display? At least, in standard EL prior to Java EE 6 you cannot pass method arguments like that. In [JBoss-EL](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest-2/reference/en-US/html/elenhancements.html) or in [Java EE 6 EL](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) you can do that. The syntax would then just have been:

```
${teacherBean.certificationFor(particularField)}
```

Note that you cannot nest EL expressions, an EL expression is already a whole expression at its own.

In standard EL implementations you can however access `Map` values by keys using the brace notation. Thus, if you for example have a `Map<String, String> certifications` where the keys corresponds the `particularField` and the values the associated value:

```
private Map<String, String> certifications = new HashMap<String, String>();

public Map<String, String> getCertificationFor() {
    return this.certifications;
}
```

then you can use the following notation:

```
${teacherBean.certificationFor[particularField]}
```

this resolves behind the scenes to

```
teacherBean.getCertificationFor().get(particularField)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in the standard EL you don't have any options other than defining your functions wrapped in a EL function;

Read: http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html near the bottom of the 
document;

but as BalusC mentioned already if you could use another EL implmentation if you have the ability to add that kind of dependency to your app

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
${teacherBean.certificationFor(particularField)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing a general functionality that is better expressed as a separate function, then you can write it as follows:

```
${certificationFor[teacherBean][particularField]}
```

where certificationFor maps to the CertificationFor class which extends [ELMethod.java](http://vineetmanohar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/com/vineetmanohar/util/ELMethod.java) class. You implement the functionality in the `result(Object[] args)` method. The args to this method are the args that you passed to the `${certificationFor}` object in EL.

```
public class CertificationFor extends ELMethod {
  public Object result(Object[] args) {  
    TeacherBean teacherBean = (TeacherBean) args[0];  
    String property = (String) args[1];

    // your implementation goes here
    return ....;
  }
}
```

The trick is to use your object as a chained map of maps, that is one way to pass multiple args to EL function.

If you are interested, you can see full code and code snippets here:
http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/07/how-to-pass-parameters-in-el-methods/