# JSF: <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.method([abc])}" />

Tags: java, xhtml, ehcache, jsf-1.2

I have a bean and there is cache and a method to get value from it.

```
public List<SelectItem> getSelectItemList(String key){
 return cache.get(key).getValue();
}
```

May I know how can I get this list in JSF?

I have tried..

```
 <f:selectItems value="#{Bean.getSelectItemList(abc)}" />
```

but it does not work, because it is expecting a property.

Note: I using JSF 1.2 , EHCache

Comment: I'm not sure if your EL supports passing parameters. Assuming it does, you need to send `abc` as a `String` using `#{Bean.getSelectItemList('abc')}`

Comment: did that too, but it does not work.

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible with JSF-1.2

Comment: Then maybe your EL library doesn't support passing parameter at all.

Comment: @Thor passing parameters or not in EL is not a JSF issue, that depends on the EL library. BalusC explains this as well (I don't have the link at hand atm)

Comment: @Thor found a link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1961248/1065197

Comment: thanks Luiggi, that is the current implementation. I refactor-ed out the hashmap and now it is using EHCache. =X it won't work anymore for me.

Comment: Can't you load this list in the `@PostConstruct public void init()` method of your managed bean?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza do you mean getting the list out of the cache  and have  the same map? =X what is the point of refactoring into EHCache in the first place.

Comment: I mean to have `private List<SelectItem> lstItems;` attribute in your managed bean with plain getter/setter (no extra business logic) and just load the info in the manage bean construction or postconstruction: `public Bean() { lstItems = cache.get("abc").getValue() }`

Comment: that will mean when I have a new key and List<SelectItem> I have to recompile my java code.. currently I just need to edit the .xhtml page when I got a new set of select items.

Answer (score 0):

JSF Code:

```
 <t:selectOneMenu id="testId" value="#{testBean.selectedItem}" >
      <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.selectItemList}" />
 </t:selectOneMenu>
```

Manage Bean code:

```
    private String selectedItem;    
    private List selectItemList;
public List<SelectItem> getselectItemList() {
        if(null == selectItemList || selectItemList.isEmpty()){
            selectUserList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
            selectItemList.add(new SelectItem(this.selectedItem, cache.get(this.selectedItem).getValue()));
        }
        return selectItemList;
    }
```